# Is there a fix for UGreen USB-C to HDMI cable not working in Catalina?

Tags: display, usb, catalina, hdmi

I have a UGreen 4K Nylon USB-C to HDMI cable which mysteriously stopped working with my 2016 15" MacBook Pro as soon as I upgraded to Catalina.

Has anyone else had issues with this cable and are there any fixes?

NB: my computer works fine with the Apple HDMI adapter into the same screen.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Maybe related? Some aspects are similar: [Macbook Pro loses the connection to USB adapter after sleeping](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/391830/100490)

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it using the same HUB, connect to this display and after change to old hub.

It's strange but works for me.

Comment: "same hub"/"old hub"... What hub? "This display"... what display? Please [edit] your answer and clarify what you mean.